# What language should I write a command shell in?

Tags: shell

I'm looking for a language that, while being flexible **and** very light on memory usage, is still easy to use (if not PHP, JavaScript or Python, I know those already). I have to write a command shell, so that users who log in by SSH are limited to this app. What language should I choose?

Comment: For what to they need a shell, if they are limited to just one app?

Comment: Please add some details, why should it be light on memory usage? What is the aim of this shell?

Comment: Not really, I consider the app a command shell. The thing is, it needs to be light because the server isn't that powerful, and it needs to run other services at the same time, so I'm looking at less than 10-15MB per instance. All it will do is execute commands based on user selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to "sandbox" users after they are logged in, an important aspect is security: You have to make sure there is no way for a user to "break out" of the sandbox. As a consequence I would vote against using a language where you have to manage memory by yourself, as it is very easy to make mistakes which have security implications. So no C or C++. I also would not use PHP for security reasons.

Python sounds most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

if you already know python, write it in python, and for limiting the resources accessible from SSH depends on the OS.

Check the security model implementations of [Mandatory Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control#Implementations).